# Returning the integral of a vector

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to create a function, which returns a vector and then integrating it element by element. This is what I have so far

```
def int1(b):
    j = 1
    for q in range(0,len(alpha)):
        j = j + alpha[q]*(b**q)
    p = np.exp(-j);
    inu = np.zeros(len(alpha))
    for q in range(0,len(alpha)):
        inu[q] = np.exp(-j)*(b**q)
    return inu
```

This works if I type something like

```
print int1(0.1)[2]
```

However

```
print sp.integrate.quad(int1(b)[2], 1e-16, 1, epsrel=1e-20)[0]
```

does not work, or any reasonable variant I can think of. How can I get it to work?
either i get TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**' if i leave out the b or ValueError: invalid callable given if I have it in.

Comment: Could you please check the indentation changes I made and correct as needed.  I am not sure of your intent and the original indentation was not correct.

Comment: How could `int1(b)[2]` work since you only `return` a single value? If you returned multiple results, then you're indexing a particular result. If you return a single string, well you're picking a character in that string, and so on...

Comment: @roganjosh I return an array? or list (i believe its called in python). I should have len(alpha) entries and I want to integrate it with respect to b.

Comment: @PyNEwbie the indents might have gotten funny because of getting to to register as code but it worked fine on my machine.

Comment: @user2720867 Your function returns a NumPy array. Python has lists, NumPy has arrays. They are similar but different types of collections.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) must be a function, something that call be called. Something that you can put (0.1) after and it will make sense. Does `int1(b)[2](0.1)` make sense? To me neither.

The form `quad(int1, 1e-16, 1, epsrel=1e-20)[0]` is syntactically correct but `quad` only allows scalar outputs of the function, so it won't work with your `int1`. Instead, you need to make a new function that uses `int1` but then returns only one of its components. Instead of having another `def` somewhere, it's better to make such a function right where it is needed, using [`lambda` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
quad(lambda b: int1(b)[2], 1e-16, 1, epsrel=1e-20)[0]
```

This says: take `b`, put it in `int1`, keep the index-2 entry of the returned array.